# Usando Promise.resolve().then() corretamente Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript, promises

Oi, tenho o seguinte código:

```js
export class Page {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

  private async openModal(value) {    
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AnotherPage,
      componentProps: {
        "paramID": 123,
        "paramTitle": "Test Title",
        "takenPhoto": "null"
      }
    });

    return await modal.present();
  }

  public async takePicture() {
    this.openModel(null); // aqui dá certo
    Promise.resolve(this.someMethod()).then(this.openModal); // aqui dá erro
  }

}
```

No método `takePicture` eu quero abrir um modal após executar o `Promise.resolve`. Na primeira execução da função tudo dá certo, mas na segunda dá erro.

O erro é esse:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalController' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalController' of undefined
    at tab2.page.ts:25
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at tslib.es6.js:73
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:876)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:69)
    at openModal (tab2.page.ts:22)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Alguém sabe como resolver? Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Isso é problema com o contexto do `this`. `this` se refere ao objeto no qual o método é executado, não ao objeto no qual o método é declarado.

Se o seu método `openModal` for passado como parâmero para ser executado em algum outro contexto, `this` irá se referir à esse outro contexto, e não ao contexto do seu objeto `Page`. Por isso ele não consegue encontrar a propriedade `modalController`, pois essa propriedade não existe nesse outro contexto.

A maneira mais fácil de contornar esse problema é passando uma `arrow function` como parâmetro, pois com esse tipo de função não é feito o binding do `this`, ou seja, o valor de `this` não será alterado para o outro contexto.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
class Foo {
  resolvePromise() {
    Promise.resolve().then(function() {
      console.log('Em Foo, this dentro da Promise se refere a:', this) // undefined
    })
  }
}

class Bar {
  resolvePromise() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      console.log('Em Bar, this dentro da Promise se refere a:', this) // bar
    })
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()
const bar = new Bar()

foo.resolvePromise()
bar.resolvePromise()
```

Então para o seu problema, utilize:

```
Promise.resolve(this.someMethod()).then(() => this.openModal());
```